# Magento 2.3 fresh install vs. upgrade

Tags: magento2.3

I'm getting frustrated with up grading from `magento 2.2 to 2.3`. no matter what I try I keep getting stuck step by step and it's getting really frustrating.

Right now I'm getting stuck at the **symphony errors**, and yes I have already read the threads about how to get rid of those but it's just not working for me.

If I were to do a **fresh install of 2.3** and then transfer over order data `products and customer data`. What would be wrong with that?

The only real issue for me would be transferring over the customer data. Because I would want customers to still be able to log into their accounts using their password. I don't care if they can see their previous order information. But I would want their passwords to work.

Comment: nothing wrong with that you can actually migrate specific tables data to your new Magento database

Comment: My current guess would be that the symfony errors are either coming from the require-dev requirements of Magento or some other 3rd party extension that you have currently installed. Doing a fresh install would help with the former but not the latter. This guide is pretty good to follow https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html and I suggest posting your specific issue that you might need assistance with.

Comment: Why don't you try using the same database of Magento 2.2 to be used with Magento 2.3 fresh install.Try installing Magento 2.3, once installed change to the existing database then upgrade and deploy.